# Secound countable inverse limit is essentially countable

Tags: general-topology, compactness, limits-colimits

One can show the following: if $I$ is a directed set and $(A_i)_i$ is a surjective inverse system of compact Hausdorff spaces such that the inverse limit $A=\lim_{i\in I} A_i$ is second countable, then the limit is essentially countable, i.e. there is a countable directed $J\subseteq I$ such that $A=\lim_{j\in J} A_j$.

I am curious how sharp this result is. In particular, does it fail if:

1. We no longer assume that $A_i$ are compact?
2. Alternatively, we no longer assume that $(A_i)_i$ is surjective?
3. Putting those two together, if neither $A_i$ nor $A$ is compact and the system is not surjective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a counterexample where the maps are not surjective.  Let $S$ be an uncountable set and let $I$ be the set of cofinite subsets of $S$ ordered by reverse inclusion.  Let $A_i=[0,1]^i$; if $i\subseteq j$ let the map $A_i\to A_j$ be the inclusion that is $0$ on all the coordinates of $j\setminus i$.  Then the inverse limit is just a singleton (the intersection of all the $A_i$ inside $[0,1]^S$), but the inverse limit of any countable subsystem is $[0,1]^T$ for some cocountable $T\subseteq S$.

And here is a counterexample where the spaces are not compact.  Let $I=\omega_1$ and let $A_i$ be the set of injections $i\to\mathbb{N}$ whose image has infinite complement, with the discrete topology.  The natural restriction map $A_j\to A_i$ is then surjective when $j\geq i$.  Any element of the inverse limit determines an injection $\omega_1\to\mathbb{N}$, and so the inverse limit is empty and hence second countable.  But the inverse limit of any countable subsystem is nonempty, since if $i\in\omega_1$ is the supremum of indices of the subsystem, the inverse limit naturally contains $A_i$.

Comment: I like the first example. I'm not sure if I understand the second one though. I guess in the conclusion, you meant that the inverse limit is the set of injections, not surjections? And what do you think happens of $A_i$ are noncompact Polish?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if I feel comfortable with the statement that the limit is the set of injections. I guess a posteriori this is true for obvious reasons, but maybe it'd be better to say that it is *a* set of injections (and hence empty). Also, in the first example, it should be $i\subseteq j$.

Comment: Oops, thanks for catching all those little errors; I think I've fixed everything.  You can tweak the second example to have Polish spaces by building a similar inverse limit which is empty but where you only take a countable subset of $A_i$ at each step (choose those countable subsets one by one to ensure the restrictions maps remain surjective; you can do this since there are only countably many previous stages of the construction).

Comment: This construction is known as an [Aronszajn tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aronszajn_tree).

Comment: Oh, actually constructing an Aronszajn tree is more delicate than what I said before (the construction I outlined might not work since at limit steps there could be no injections compatible with the earlier steps whose image has infinite complement).  Anyways, there's a construction that does work (using increasing functions to $\mathbb{Q}$ rather than arbitrary injections) at the link above.

Comment: And to be a bit more precise about the terminology: an Aronszajn tree is an inverse system of sets of length $\omega_1$ where each set is countable and nonempty but the inverse limit is empty.  The maps are not necessarily surjective.  However, given any Aronszajn tree, you can take a subsystem consisting of just those elements which lift to every higher term in the system, and that will still be an Aronszajn tree and its maps will be surjective.